# Mutate column as input to sample

Tags: r, sample, dplyr

I want create a distribution using the `sample()` function with the probability of each value defined by a `data.frame()` column. When I try the code below however it produces the error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

I'm guessing this is because mutate is passing the entire column and not just one integer. Can anyone help me with this?

```
library(dplyr)

input = data.frame(input = 1:100)
output = input %>% mutate(output = 
                            sum(
                              sample(0:1, 
                                     10, 
                                     replace = T,
                                     prob = c(input, 100-input)
                                     )))
```

Comment: `prob` needs to be of length 2 one each for 0 and 1 that you are sampling. The output of `c(input, 100-input)` has length 101.

Answer (score 2):

I have determined that the solution was to use the `rowwise()` function in the pipe expression:

```
library(dplyr)

input = data.frame(input = 1:100)
output = input %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(output = 
                            sum(
                              sample(0:1, 
                                     100, 
                                     replace = T,
                                     prob = c(input, 1)
                                     )))
```